# I need to host large mp3 files & link them on website for download

Tags: web-hosting, cloud-hosting

I have a requirement where i need to lost large mp3 files on a web server. file size may vary from 1MB - 120MB (where most of the files are more than 20MB)

With large size in mind i cant host these files on the same web server as can slow down the web-server & degrade performance of several websites hosted on the same server.

I would appreciate if someon can tell me which is the best service paid service to host these files for streaming & downloading.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is difficult to say what is the best service without knowing what criteria represent 'best' (value for money, transfer rates, server uptime, continuity of service, length of existence, domain credibility are some possible criteria) - but I've never had trouble with [We Transfer](https://www.wetransfer.com/).